# Texture is not loading through glGenerateMipmap()

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl, textures

I can't load texture through `glGenerateMipmap` on my cube.

I load the BMP texture from `resource.h` file.

**My load function is called on `WM_CREATE` and looks like this:**

```
void LoadTEX()
{
 GLuint texture;  
 HBITMAP GLtex;
 BITMAP tex;
 byte Texture=TEX;
 GLtex= (HBITMAP)LoadImage(GetModuleHandle(NULL),MAKEINTRESOURCE(Texture), IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_CREATEDIBSECTION);

  GetObject(GLtex,sizeof(tex), &tex);
  glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT,sizeof(Texture));
  glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
  glGenTextures(sizeof(Texture), &texture);
  glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture );
  glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_DECAL);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP, GL_TRUE);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST );
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );  
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
  glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D,
            0,
            GL_RGB,
            tex.bmWidth,
            tex.bmHeight,
            0,
            GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
            tex.bmBits);

 glDeleteTextures(sizeof(Texture), &texture);
}
```

**On `WM_PAINT`:**

```
 glColor3f(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
 glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
 glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture );
 // glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
 // glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
 gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 3, tex.bmWidth, tex.bmHeight, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, tex.bmBits);
```

The above code works fine (texture is in place) but the problem is that it gives me 40 FPS which is very poor result (without texture been bonded I get around 300 FPS).

Second is that I don't want to use `gluBuild2DMipmaps` because it's a bit old, instead  I want to use `glGenerateMipmap`. Problem is that if I comment out `gluBuild2DMipmaps` and uncomment `glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);`, `glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D)` nothing is shown.

**My `PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR` looks like:**

```
PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd;
int format;

// get the device context (DC)
*hdc = GetDC( hwnd );

// set the pixel format for the DC
ZeroMemory( &pfd, sizeof( pfd ) );
pfd.nSize = sizeof( pfd );
pfd.nVersion = 1;
pfd.dwFlags = PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER;
pfd.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
pfd.cColorBits = 32;
pfd.cDepthBits = 32;
pfd.iLayerType = PFD_MAIN_PLANE;
format = ChoosePixelFormat( *hdc, &pfd );
SetPixelFormat( *hdc, format, &pfd );
```

All this running on ATI and OPENGL 3.1 support. I call the `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);` so this should work with ati cards so the problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

In LoadTEX, don't delete the texture straight after loading it. (Also it should be glGenTextures(1, &texture) and glDeleteTextures(1, &texture) to generate and delete one texture handle)

Then call glGenerateMipmap after loading it with glTexImage2D. Unless the texture changes and you need to regenerate the mipmaps each frame, in which case leave the call where it is.

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0) is the default anyway. If you were binding other textures at the same time you'd use glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1) or glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + textureIndex) etc.

I'm not sure on the specifics of windows bitmap loading, but double check the glPixelStorei line, given the other sizeof(Texture) uses I have to assume this may be incorrect too. To be safe, just set it to 1 byte.

Comment: I have pasted `glTexImage2D` before 'glGenerateMipmap' on my draw function. The result was that exception was thrown and MS Visual Studio colored red the value from `tex.bmBits: 0x005f0000`. I use 512x512 BMP file with 24 Pixel Bits. Isn't that too small /big for glTexImage2D?

Comment: A crash on glTexImage2D suggests OpenGL is trying to read some invalid data. This means it's expecting something to be there and it's not. Either 1. tex.bmBits is invalid/uninitialized/null, 2. width/height are too big (causing over-read), 3. GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT is too big, causing more data to be read than exists, 4. there are less than 3 channels and GL_RGBA expects 3. Also jut to double check, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE should be used as is in your example.

Comment: @NightKn8 The first line of this answer is the most important. Why on earth create a texture and then delete it right afterwards. Every use of the texture ID afterwards is bound to result in errors or weird behaviour. So the simple answer is **drop that `glDeleteTextures` call**. And of course the answer is also right in that you should really think if it's neccessary to rebuild the mipmaps each and every frame. But the best answer would probably for to look a bit deeper into how textures and OpenGL objects actually work.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following order during loading of texture:

```
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, n2width, n2height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixmap);

glHint(GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP_HINT, GL_FASTEST);//GL_FASTEST);
glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D); // Generate mip mapping
```

And dont rebuild mipmaps on every frame.